# Why is it important that the $p$-adic absolute value satisfy multiplicativity?

Tags: absolute-value, p-adic-number-theory, motivation, multiplicative-function

I suppose my question is really "why do we require norms in general to satisfy multiplicativity?". I ask this because for the usual absolute value on $\mathbb R$, I never feel like multiplicativity plays any "key role"; compare this to for example the omnipresent triangle inequality for the usual absolute value on $\mathbb R$, and in general in any metric space.

Suppose we are learning about $p$-adic numbers for the first time, say via this nice presentation: [https://math.uchicago.edu/~tghyde/Hyde%20--%20Introduction%20to%20p-adics.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Etghyde/Hyde%20--%20Introduction%20to%20p-adics.pdf). I get that we would like some sort of norm $|a|_n$ for $a\in \mathbb Z_n$ that is smaller for values of $a$ that have a larger number $N$ of rightmost zeroes (in base $n$), and I agree something like $c^{-N}$ is a natural choice (really given the limited menagerie of "standard elementary functions" that's pretty much our only choice, other than perhaps an inverse power function like $\frac 1N$ or $\frac 1{N^k}$), but why do we emphasize that such a norm MUST be multiplicative?

EDIT: basically, I’m looking for the easiest example of the $p$-adic norm being used in some application to prove something “interesting” (outside the abstract theory of absolute values), that requires multiplicativity; in particular this rules out Ostrowski’s theorem.

Sort-of related is [Why does the p-adic norm use base p?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482489/why-does-the-p-adic-norm-use-base-p) since it is sort of related to this "motivating the $p$-adic norm" business I have going on here.

Comment: The multiplicativity of the absolute values is used in [Ostrowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem), which classifies the possible equivalence classes of absolute values over $\mathbb{Q}$ (either the usual absolute value, or one of the $p$-adic ones). Without that, there could be a lot more, for example $f\left(\left|x\right|\right)$ for any function $f: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ satisfying $f(x + y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(x) = 0$ iff $x = 0$.

Comment: So having the multiplicativity seems to enforce a certain structure there. But I guess that reason is not very convincing if you don't really care about these absolute values.

Comment: Also having multiplicativity helps with computations, and in the $p$-adic case in particular, is useful to compute the $p$-valuation of binomial coefficients $n \choose k$, which comes up in number theory.

Comment: @TobErnack yes my question is in part due to Ostrowski's theorem, since many sources say "ahh, the $p$-adic norm is not arbitrary, since by Ostrowski's theorem all absolute values on $\mathbb Q$ are the standard one or the $p$-adic ones" but yes as you pointed this out this just pushes the "arbitrariness" one step back, to now why are we only considering absolute values, i.e. "multiplicative functions measuring size", instead of just "functions measuring size".

Comment: If you consider norm $N$ on a vector space $V$ over $K\subseteq \mathbb C$, then you have the axiom of absolute homogeneity $N(\alpha x)=|\alpha|N(x)$ which plays well with our intuition of length (if I double the size of an object, its length should double as well). In the familiar case of $\mathbb R$, absolute value is a norm and positive homogeneity is just multiplicativity. If you want to consider absolute value on an arbitrary field $K$, assuming multiplicativity, therefore, makes it analogous to the notion of norm for vector spaces in general (and $K$ is a vector space over itself).

Comment: Perhaps it helps to add that with the “standard” absolute values, $\Bbb Q$ is  “Product formula field”, i.e. for a nonzero rational $z$, $\prod_{\mathrm {all}}|z|_{\mathfrak p}=1$. (The norms have to be adjusted for other number fields…)

Answer (score 4):

I apologize in advance that my answer is somehow nonmathematical, but I believe it's one aspect of the situation.

Other comments and answers have provided evidence that multiplicativity is an essential assumption in many results concerning $p$-adic norms. But if you think about how mathematical research is done, then the answer might be just the other way around.

Why do we require the $p$-adic norm to satisfy multiplicativity? Because researches in this direction turned out to produce many interesting and useful results, such as Ostrowski's theorem, while not much could be done without this requirement.

As a comparison, consider the related question of why $p$-adic norm uses prime number $p$. It turns out that in earlier literatures, there exists "$g$-adic (pseudo-)norm" with not necessarily prime $g$ (see e.g. *Introduction to $p$-adic Numbers and their Functions*, by Kurt Mahler). But not many important results have been established for these pseudonorms, hence you don't see them very often now.

Comment: “Other comments and answers have provided evidence that multiplicative is an essential assumption in many results” — no, so far not one such result has been mentioned (I do not count Ostrowski’s theorem since that is not so much about situations where we apply the p-adic norm to prove something from number theory, say)

Comment: By the way, I think the right way to view Ostrowski's theorem *is* to view it as a theorem in number theory. Let $|\cdot|$ be any absolute value so that $\mathbb{Z}$ is in the closed unit ball around $0$. Then Ostrowski's theorem says that there is a prime $p$ such that $|x| = 1$ if and only if $x$ belongs to the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $p\mathbb{Z}$. I don't see why you do not consider this a number theoretic result, unless you are choosing to interpret "number theory" extremely narrowly.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you loosen the restriction of multiplicativity to submultiplicativity, you get a far more intricate theory which seems to be not fully developed yet, but which (as @asahay points out in his answer and comments) connects naturally to nonarchimedean functional analysis (books by Bosch/Güntzer/Remmert, and Schneider), to Berkovich Spaces, and to Scholze's Perfectoid Spaces. See Kedlaya's paper *On Commutative Nonarchimedean Banach Fields* ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.09004)) for a good introduction.

As a first teaser, note that for any finite family (and many infinite families) $(\Vert \Vert_i :i \in I)$ of submultiplicative ring norms, their supremum is again a submultiplicative ring norm. I have an inkling that on $\mathbb Q$, all submultiplicative norms arise in this way from the multiplicative absolute values well-known via Ostrowski, but to be honest I'm not even in possession of a proof for that.

Answer (score 2):

The $p$-adic norm on $\mathbb{Q}$ is a standard example of an [algebraic absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_(algebra)). In particular, we are viewing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a ring (more specifically an integral domain) here, and so the only notions of absolute values that are of interest are the ones that respect the ring operations. None of the other axioms refer to ring multiplication in any way, so the requirement that $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ be multiplicative can be thought of as the simplest way to make the absolute value respect the ring multiplication.

Comment: The axioms of an absolute value “respect” the additive and multiplicative ring structure differently...I do not find this answer convincing

Comment: Yes, they respect the additive and multiplicative structure differently. You can choose to consider a structure which is submultiplicative rather than multiplicative (see, for example https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/normed+ring ), but I've never seen a naturally arising submultiplicative norm on a field that is not a (multiplicative) absolute value. If neither this, nor Ostrowski's theorem are enough to convince you that this is a natural object to study, then I'm afraid I don't have any answers for you.

Comment: One last comment, as a counterpoint to what I said about naturally arising submultiplicative norms on fields being multiplicative. This is not true for more general rings -- the classic example are operator/matrix norms.